# You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression error

Tags: .net, ms-access

I have a below query

```
SELECT 
   MonthNumber, 
   Sum(PhaseCost) AS PC, Sum(TotalCost) TC,
   PC / (TC-PC) AS PER 
FROM 
   Table1 
JOIN  
   Table2 ON Table1.MonthNumber = Table2.MonthNumber 
GROUP BY  
   MonthNumber
```

It just works fine and returns a record in MS Access, however when I try to call the same from .Net I get this error

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression PC/(TC-PC), And SUM(PC/(TC_PC)) is not allowed.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference `PC` and `TC` that way. You must use their calculations in lieu of their aliases.

It should, instead, be written as:

```
SELECT MonthNumber, 
Sum(PhaseCost) AS PC, 
Sum(TotalCost) AS TC, 
Sum(PhaseCost)/(Sum(TotalCost)-Sum(PhaseCost)) AS PER 
FROM Table1 Join Table2 ON Table1.MonthNumber = Table2.MonthNumber 
Group By MonthNumber
```

Disclaimer: I did not test this SQL.